# Pendulum force components at maximum displacement

Tags: forces

[image]

If $\theta$ is the maximum angle for the pendulum's swing, then should $T\cos\theta=mg$ or should $T=mg\cos\theta$.

I think that the components must be done in the perpendicular directions $T\cos\theta=mg$ as the bob can't go any further. Can anybody please help me by telling me what would be the correct choice?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Your expression for the projection of the normal force is valid throughout all movement, not only at a maximum angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

\begin{equation}
T-mg\cos\theta=m\,a_\textrm{centripetal}=m\,\dfrac{v^{2}}{r}
\tag{01}
\end{equation}
At maximum $\:\theta\:$ since $\:v=0\:$
\begin{equation}
T-mg\cos\theta=0
\tag{02}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

> I think that the components must be done in the perpendicular directions $T\cos\theta=mg$ **as the bob can't go any further**.

It is wrong. Because $\Sigma \vec F=\vec 0$ doesn't mean that the bob will be fixed. A body can move because of its **inertia** even if $\Sigma \vec F=\vec 0$ (first law of Newton).

Comment: Sir as i have mentioned for the maximum angle $\theta$, can the bob still go up? Can you please elaborate sir?

Comment: No, it cannot. But, not because of $\Sigma \vec F=\vec 0$!

Comment: So even at maximum displacement, is there any perpendicular force acting on it?

Comment: No, I am saying you got wrong because of a wrong assumption.

Comment: OK, thank you sir. Can there be any way to know such things? Its visible that the bob won't go ahead, so can there be any way to check whether its due to no existence of force or its just due to zero velocity?

Comment: You can know this by considering the conditions **before** fixing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41761/discussion-between-harsh-sharma-and-lucas).

Comment: I am sorry dear Harsh. I wouldn't like to come to chat because of some personal reasons. I am sure that there are some people in h bar chatroom that can help you. Sorry again and good luck.